# JSON array in html table with div inserted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I want to know how to turn json into html table

php

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT `Name`,`Author` FROM `details`;");
$array_name = Array();
$array_author = Array();


while($result = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $array_name[] = $result['Name'];
    $array_author[] = $result['Author'];
}

echo json_encode(array('name'=>$array_name, 'author' =>$array_author));
```

js

```
function getbook(){
var json;
$.ajax({
    url: "getbook.php", 
    datatype: "json", 
    async:true,
    success: function(response) {
        json = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(json);

}, 
    error: function() {
      console.log("ajax error!"); 
    }
 });
```

I hope the result is like

```
Name    Name    Name
Author  Author  Author
```

with the name and the author in the same `<td>` if possible
also is it possible to insert div in every `<td>` generated?

Comment: Do a little research, start with `.html()` jquery function.

Comment: I'd suggest you to not save name and author in different arrays. Just do something like `$arr[] = array('Name' => $result['Name'], 'Author' => $result['Author']);`. And in the javascript you just loop the object acessing `var.Name` and `var.Author`.

Comment: @FirstOne You mean in `while` ? then should json encode be `json_encode($arr);` ?

Comment: @AgnesLeung exactly ^^. Don't forget to create `$arr = array();` **before** the `while`.

Comment: visit this to get more info https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-properly-populate-html-table-with-jquery-ajax-using-json-formatted-data/202187

Answer (score 0):

I would insert the `name` and the `author` in the same array :

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT `Name`,`Author` FROM `details`;");
$data = array();

while($result = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[] = [
        'name' => $result['Name'],
        'author' => $result['Author']
    ];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

It will build your json array like :

```
[{"name":"Some Name","author":"John Doe"},{"name":"Another Name","author":"Mary Jane"}]
```

Then from JS success function :

```js
// create sample json array for demonstration
var data = [{"name":"Some Name","author":"John Doe"},{"name":"Another Name","author":"Mary Jane"}];

// ...

$('body').append('<table id="details" class="table"><thead><tr><td>Name</td><td>Author</td></tr></thead><tbody>');

data.forEach(function(details) {
    $('#details').append('<tr><td>'+details.name+'</td><td>'+details.author+'</td></tr>');
});

$('body').append('</tbody></table>');

// ...
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

So th JS part will look like this :

```
function getbook(){
    var json;
    $.ajax({
        url: "getbook.php", 
        datatype: "json", 
        async:true,
        success: function(response) {
            $('body').append('<table id="details"><thead><tr><td>Name</td><td>Author</td></tr></thead><tbody>');
            data.forEach(function(details) {
                $('#details').append('<tr><td>'+details.name+'</td><td>'+details.author+'</td></tr>');
            });
            $('body').append('</tbody></table>');
        }, 
        error: function() {
            console.log("ajax error!"); 
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps.